# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined error on another device

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, localhost

[image][image]So I am viewing my website on my phone. I am doing this by putting the ip address of the host computer and than the port the website is on. However When I try to view the website on my phone I get the error TypeError:Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. This error does not come up when I view the website on my computer. I am not sure why I am getting this error and I am not sure which part of my code to post since I don't know where the error is coming from. I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS for the background. I am using ReactJS and Redux for the frontend. Any help is appreciated! If any clarification is needed let me know.

Comment: I don't see how we can help you without more to go on to troubleshoot.  Obviously, you have to eventually figure out which part of your code is causing that error.  If you can't get debugging info out of the error on the device that causes the problem, then you have to instrument your code with some sort of debug statements to narrow down where the error is being triggered.  Not much we can help here in any more specific way.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error

Comment: This is likely caused by a line of your code where you aren't passing a proper parameter.  So, I'd suggest following up the stack frame of the error and find the first place that it's your own code and diagnose from there.

Comment: I didn't fin anything helpful in the stack frame. Could it be the device since none of my other devices show this error and there is nothing in the console as well.

Comment: It's kind of hard to blame it on the device itself.  I would say that the code is not correct for that device or for the state that exists on that device.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's true. What steps could I take next to solve this issue if I couldn't find anything in the stack frames. Just to be clear this error pops up on my android phone on chrome.

Comment: There's not enough context/code for what you're doing in your question to have any idea how to debug it.

Comment: Please migrate to redux-toolkit: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Redux Dev Tools? Because if so, I had this error too since I was using `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` this line in `compose()`. Taking it out solved it for me.

Comment: Please see that compose takes function which does not return any value. Here it will return boolean, so only window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() might work. Other check can be taken in an outer block: if(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__){// initialise using compose} like https://stackoverflow.com/a/65772804/787399

Answer (score 2):

You can replace store.js by

```
const composeEnhancers = typeof window === "object" && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({})
: compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, enhancer);
export default store;
```